# Grunt - Change bower components directory?

Tags: gruntjs, bower, bower-install

How do I change the `bower_components` directory to something custom when using grunt for development? I want to set a custom folder such as `scripts` for all my libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add and use `.bowerrc` file to define `bower_components` custom path. (http://bower.io/docs/config/)

Comment: Thanks! Please let me try this and get back.

Comment: Do you possibly know how to persist this path to grunt? It keeps updating my dependencies with the wrong path. E.g. `components/depfolder/dep` instead of `resources/components/depfolder/dep`